# Python: Commit Shape Key deformations (for all selected objects)

Tags: python, shape-keys

I want to be able to "commit" (or "realize") all Shape Key deformations on multiple selected objects using Python.

By this I mean: create a New Shape From Mix, then delete all *other* shapes, then finally delete the mix result shape, leaving the selected objects altered but with no more shape key data.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
sel_objs = context.selected_objects
```

for each selected object...

**New Shape From Mix**

```
bpy.ops.object.shape_key_add(from_mix=True)
```

Get the number of shape key indices.

Iterate through and remove all except the last (leaving the last one as the true shape):

```
bpy.ops.object.shape_key_remove(all=False)
```

Then remove the final remaining one as well (for cleanup).

I'm unclear on some of the details when putting this all together. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I've done this in one project:

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
objs = context.selected_objects

for ob in objs:
    ob.hide_viewport = False  # should be visible
    if ob.data.shape_keys:
         ob.shape_key_add(name='CombinedKeys', from_mix=True)
         for shapeKey in ob.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:
             ob.shape_key_remove(shapeKey)
```

Avoid using `ops`, because you have to set context override every time, it is quite difficult because you have to guess that values have to be overridden

Comment: Thank you! It seems you're not specifying the order of key deletion. Is that because the newly added "CombinedKeys" is indexed last, and therefore automatically gets deleted last?

Comment: Yes. you are right.